# Creating DBMS_SCHEDULER job for oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, dbms-scheduler

Trying to create job But can't compile it keeps me given this error. There is a question on oracle forums, it say's that i have to create program to wrap it. Is there any workaround for [this?](https://community.oracle.com/message/9650591#9650591)

[image: It gives me this Error]

```
 -- Created on 30.09.2014 by ALI.ORHAN 
    declare
      -- Local variables here
      i integer;
    begin
      -- Test statements here
      dbms_scheduler.create_job(job_name        => 'blabla'
                               ,job_type        => 'STORED_PROCEDURE'
                               ,job_action      => 'dingdongprocedure;'
                               ,start_date      => '30-OCT-14 10.00.00 PM'
                               ,end_date        => '15-JULY-08'
                               ,repeat_interval => 'FREQ=WEEKLY BYDAY=TUE,FRI BYHOUR=10,13'
                               ,enable          => 'TRUE'
                               ,comments        => 'SUPREME COMMENT');
    end;
```

After i created job from PL/SQL Developer UI, i found out my syntax erorrs, new code is below;

1. i use sys.dbms_scheduler.create_job instead of dbms_scheduler.create_job. I don't know differances but it's not important alteration.
2. i used to_date to define start_date, as a fresh-starter i found this better practise.
3. **Important** I added job_class parameter to 'DBMS_JOB$'. DBMS_JOB is built_in job class of Oracle RDBMS. So you find all jobs with this query:

   ```
   select * from  ALL_SCHEDULER_JOBS WHERE JOB_CLASS='DBMS_JOB$'
   ```
4. **Important** My interval's were wrong you should put ; between all parameters like

   ```
   repeat_interval => freq=weekly;byhour=10, 13
   ```
5. My first job code has another syntax error i use **enable** instead of **enabled**.
6. I set auto_drop false. I guess this parameter is used to drop job when it dones his job. I mean if you create a job that makes changes daily from today to next week. After end-time reaches, this job has dropped. Please correct me if i wrong.

   ```
   sys.dbms_scheduler.create_job(job_name        => 'BOMBASTICJOB'
                            ,job_type        => 'STORED_PROCEDURE'
                            ,job_action      => 'dingdongprocedure'
                            ,start_date      => to_date('30-09-2014 00:00:00' 
                                                             , 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
                            ,end_date        => to_date(null)
                            ,job_class       => 'DBMS_JOB$'
                            ,repeat_interval => 'Freq=Weekly; ByDay=Tue, Fri; ByHour=10, 13'
                             ,enabled          => true
                             ,auto_drop       => false
                             ,comments         => '');
   ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am on 12.1.0.1.0. You could create the job in a simple anonymous block :

```
SQL> BEGIN
  2    DBMS_SCHEDULER.DROP_JOB (JOB_NAME => 'test_full_job_definition');
  3  END;
  4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
SQL> BEGIN
  2    DBMS_SCHEDULER.create_job (
  3      job_name        => 'test_full_job_definition',
  4      job_type        => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
  5      job_action      => 'BEGIN my_job_procedure; END;',
  6      start_date      => SYSTIMESTAMP,
  7      repeat_interval => 'freq=hourly; byminute=0; bysecond=0;',
  8      end_date        => NULL,
  9      enabled         => TRUE,
 10      comments        => 'Job defined entirely by the CREATE JOB procedure.');
 11  END;
 12  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT JOB_NAME, ENABLED FROM DBA_SCHEDULER_JOBS where job_name ='TEST_FULL_JOB_DEFINITION'
  2  /

JOB_NAME                                 ENABL
---------------------------------------- -----
TEST_FULL_JOB_DEFINITION                 TRUE

SQL>
```

More examples [here](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/scheduler-10g.php)

Comment: I edited my answer. No need for anonymous blocks. we can call procedure with job.

Comment: @AliArdaOrhan It is the job which needs to be created in an anonymous block. The job itself doesn't need any PL/SQL block, it just schedules the stored procedure.