# cant call and execute .sql script file in Oracle anonymous block

Tags: oracle, plsql, sql-scripts

I am trying to run the below anonymous block but getting an error `ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement`. I know its not possible to issue DDL as static SQL in a PL/SQL block in Oracle. As i have more than 50 sql scripts which needs to be executed in anonymous block its not possible to issue `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` with each and every sql statements. So thats why i have created separate script as a sql file and trying to call from my current anonymous block.

```
  SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE MESSAGE VARCHAR2(100);
CHECK_VERSION VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
--- some code to check the version
select PROP_VAL into CHECK_VERSION from RATOR_MONITORING_CONFIGURATION.RM2_PROPERTIES WHERE PROP_NAME ='DB_VERSION';
  If CHECK_VERSION != 'V3.0' then
MESSAGE := 'Wrong Version';
-- IF(VERSION WRONG) THEN
-- MEESAGE := <<provide info for user here>>
else
@UpgradeFromV2.1ToV3.0.sql;
end if;
END;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> else
>
> @UpgradeFromV2.1ToV3.0.sql;
>
> end if;

You cannot directly call a sql script inside a **PL/SQL block**. You need to externally call it.

I would suggest, put the entire **content** of the **sql script** in the PL/SQL block.

Do not confuse between **PL/SQL** and **SQL*Plus**.

- **PL/SQL** is a server side language which includes **P**rocedural **L**anguage(PL) and **S**tructured **Q**uery **L**anguage(SQL). It is executed inside an Oracle server process.
- **SQL*Plus** is a **C**ommand **L**ine **I**nterface(CLI) tool which allows you to submit SQL and PL/SQL code to the Oracle server for execution.

**Update** OP seems to have asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31872132/ora-00900-invalid-sql-statement-in-oracle-anonymous-block). And this question is related to the previous question.

You could use **[DBMS_SCHEDULER](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26115288/3989608)** and submit those sql scripts as respective **jobs**.

Calling a sql script depends on your **OS**.

For example, in **Windows**:

```
BEGIN  
  dbms_scheduler.create_job('MY_JOB',  
  job_action=>'C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CMD.EXE',  
  number_of_arguments=>3,  
  job_type=>'executable',  
  start_date => SYSTIMESTAMP,  
  repeat_interval => 'freq=hourly; byminute=0,30; bysecond=0;',  
  end_date => NULL,  
  enabled=> false);  
  dbms_scheduler.set_job_argument_value('MY_JOB',1,'/q');  
  dbms_scheduler.set_job_argument_value('MY_JOB',2,'/c');  
  dbms_scheduler.set_job_argument_value('MY_JOB',3,'D:\SCRIPTS\my_sql.bat');  
  dbms_scheduler.enable('MY_JOB');  
END;  
/
```

Now your **my_sql.bat** would look like:

```
sqlplus user@sid/password @D:\scripts\script.sql  
exit
```

Comment: in my previous question i have put all of my sql script in PL/SQL block but it doesnt work as i have to use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE  for every DDL statement.Its not possible to issue DDL as static SQL in a PL/SQL block in Oracle

Comment: *in my previous question* Which question? You did not refer it in your current question. Post the details of the sql script.

Comment: the question has been marked as duplicate and it was closed but you can see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31872132/ora-00900-invalid-sql-statement-in-oracle-anonymous-block

Comment: Ok lalit it looks complecated for me, i have to investigate more on this. But thanks i know now that its not possible to call such script file in pl sql block :)

Comment: @Rahul You need to either put the script in the block or do some complicated steps as I shown above. It is not possible to read a OS file directly from PL/SQL. Good luck!.